# Import modules from sklearn I get ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

recently I have been trying to get into machine learning, AI, ect and the tutorial i was following told me to import linear_model from sklearn what i  used to import that is as follows:

```
from sklearn import linear_models
```

if I run this code alone I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
from sklearn import linear_model
File "C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
from .least_angle import (Lars, LassoLars, lars_path, LarsCV, LassoLarsCV,
File "C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\least_angle.py", line 23, in <module>
from ..utils import arrayfuncs, as_float_array, check_X_y, deprecated
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: From your `site-packages` path, it appears you have the 32-bit version of Python.  Is your installation of sklearn also the 32-bit version?

Comment: yes i have made sure that i have the 32 bit version

Comment: Then are you sure your Python is 32-bit?

Comment: yes i am 100% certain

Comment: Do you have the correct version of Numpy installed? FWIW you might find it easier to use Anaconda if possible, especially on Windows.

Comment: @LeoFoster can you try this: from sklearn import linear_model  ??

Comment: Yes sorry I typed that wrong but no that isn't the problem